# How to compare an object to null in c#

Tags: c#, object, null

This seems like it should be really straight forward.

if I have:

```
object obj = *get value from somewhere*

if(obj == null){
    MessageBox.Show("NULL");
}
```

Even when I debug and see that obj IS null, the code never goes into the if statement.

Do you have do do something different when comparing an object to null? (because an object can be any type?)

Comment: At the moment, I just don't believe you. I suspect you're misdiagnosing something. Please produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm assuming the code is 'if(obj == null)'?

Comment: One thought: in your *actual* code, is `obj` actually statically typed as `object`? If not there's a **slim** chance you could be seeing weird behavior from some crazy overload of `==`. To be on the ultra-safe side you could always use `ReferenceEquals(obj, null)` instead.

Comment: @Toadums: Then I'm with Jon; what you're claiming is pretty incredible. (And in case you haven't guessed, the actual answer to your question is: "No, you don't have to do something different. `obj == null` should work just fine.")

Comment: Ok, i think i figured it out...When I go obj = null, it works as expected. So when debugging, I realized that when it ISNT working, the value of obj is "{null}", instead of just "null"...what does the {null} mean???

Comment: You definitely need an actual example of where this *doesn't* work. It's pretty impossible to fail a test of `if(obj == null)` when `obj` is actually `null`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, the comment's giving it away:

> Ok, in doing this, I noticed that when I hover over the variable in debugging mode, the value is null, but when it ISNT working, the value is {null}... What does {null} mean?

That suggest it's actually an array (or possibly another collection type) containing a single null reference, e.g.

```
object obj = new object[] { null };
```

The value of `obj` is *not* a null reference, hence it doesn't go into the body of the `if` statement.

How you should handle this depends on what you're trying to achieve. Do you really *need* `obj` to be statically typed as just `object`?

Comment: I believe so...I couldn't think of a better way of doing it. I am trying to make one method that can sort a list on any (that I choose) type.

Comment: I am going obj = records[0].GetValue(T), which returns either a string, int, Project, Phase, or Client. For some reason, when the Phase is null, it is set to {null}... even though it isnt a list. what does that mean? (Phase is a custom class). Oh, I am using FirstorDefault to get the phase. Default...by default is{null} ??

Comment: @Toadums: Are you sure it's not returning a `Phase` object which overrides `ToString` in a way which returns null? It would *really* help if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You should have told us all of this right from the start.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. Whoops. Thanks!! And I didn't know any of it made a difference in the start...otherwise I definitely would have told you allllll of it ;)

Comment: Oh yeah! @JonSkeet answer! Gotta +1 this one!

Answer (score 10):

You need

```
if(obj == null){
    MessageBox.Show("NULL");
}
```

You wrote the type *object* rather than your variable *obj*

**UPDATE**

Based on your edit (which changes the question quite a bit), your code should certainly work.  Try assigning

```
obj = null;
```

right before your *if* statement and see that it goes into the MessageBox.Show()

That will prove that the *if* does work as you expect it should.

**UPDATE 2**

@Jon hit it on the head that you probably have assigned an array with one element, null.  The reason it shows this way is that the debugger is trying to visualize the array.

If the array had for example two string elements "Hello" and "World" the debugger would show

{"Hello", "World"}

Since the array only has one element, null, the debugger visualizes this as

{null}

Comment: errr..ya, it is obj in code. just a typo when writing it out on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, in doing this, I noticed that when I hover over the variable in debugging mode, the value is null, but when it ISNT working, the value is {null}... What does {null} mean?